# window.open returns null while opening a cross origin request in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, windows-10, cross-domain, microsoft-edge

I am trying to launch a cross origin url using window.open(url, "_blank", null) method, window is getting opened successfully but return value is coming as null from the open method, but if I use the url of the same domain, a window(newly launched) object is being returned, it is only happening in windows 10 OS, I downloaded the edge browser on my Mac machine in that I am getting the window object properly for both same origin and cross origin requests. So is there any solution which I can follow to get the window object properly.

My application is running on a domain, for example: Domain A
I have a button in my page upon clicking the button I am calling the below code to open it in a new window.
var newWindowObject = window.open("", "_blank", null);

Comment: maybe you should provide a code sample of what you have tried?

Comment: Hi Hakan, i have updated the query, Could you please check it once.

Comment: Go to Internet options-> Security tab-> select the zone-> click Custom level button. Find and enable the option 'access data sources across domains.' Check whether it helps to get the window object properly.